# Progress bar text display issue

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I am using the following code to display % value in my progress bar.However there is some problem with the display.There is some sort of background color(of the same color as text) just behind the text(i.e. percentage value).Please help

```
Dim percent As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate((CDbl(prgProgressBar.Value - prgProgressBar.Minimum) / CDbl(prgProgressBar.Maximum - prgProgressBar.Minimum)) * 100))

Using gr As Graphics = prgProgressBar.CreateGraphics()

  gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() & "%", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Green, New PointF(prgProgressBar.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() & "%", SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2.0F), prgProgressBar.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() & "%", SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)))

End Using
```

Comment: invalidate the progressbar `prgProgressBar.Invalidate()` before drawing string `Using gr...`

Comment: OK. I add it as an answer, explain the cause of the issue and why `Invalidate` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you draw a string on the progressbar without asking it to repaint first, the old string is still there, that is why the text has the 'background color'.

By calling `Invalidate`, you force a repaint on the progress bar, and the old string is erased.

Now you have a new paper to draw new stuff.